# What should be the numbers in the fastSTRUCTURE file?

Tags: file-formats

The structure file for fastSTRUCTURE seem to be a table with rows and columns but the cells are all numbers, while my genotypes are simply bases. How could I know what I should insert there?

Comment: What format are your genotypes in at the moment? There is likely some tool someone has written to convert it to the correct format.

Comment: Just table of 'A/C' bases

Comment: 'Table' isn't a format. What are the rows? What are the columns? Is it genotypes or alleles - i.e. is there one or two rows per marker? the more info you give, the easier it will be for someone to help you. Could you add a sample of your genotype format to the main answer so others can see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numbers, usually in the form of 0/1/2, is a common way many formats represent bases.

For example, if a SNPs has bases which are A/T, then these are encoded as 0/1, with the reference allele/base taking the 0 and the alternate allele/base taking 1.

However, if you read [the documentation](https://rajanil.github.io/fastStructure/), it says:

> Specifically, rows in the data file correspond to samples, with two
> rows per sample (note that only diploids are handled by this
> software), and columns correspond to SNPs. The first 6 columns of the
> file will be ignored; these typically would include IDs, metadata,
> etc. This software only handles bi-allelic loci. **The two alleles at
> each locus can be encoded as desired**; however, missing data should be
> encoded as `-9'.

So you should be able to use your base letters here and it will work OK as long as the columns and rows are formatted correctly.